# How to convert to dates after removing the seasonality from the time series in python?

Tags: python, datetime, time-series, statsmodels

The question can be reframed as "How to remove daily seasonality from the dataset in python?"
Please read the following:
I have a time series and have used seasonal_decompose() from statsmodel to remove seasonality from the series. As I have used seasonal_decompose() on "Months" data, I get the seasonality only in months. How do I convert these months in to days/dates? Can I use seasonal_decompose() to remove daily seasonality? I tried one option of keeping frequency=365, but it raises following error:

```
 x must have 2 complete cycles requires 730 observations. x only has 24 observation(s)
```

Snippet of the code:

```
grp_month = train.append(test).groupby(data['Month']).sum()['Var1']
season_result = seasonal_decompose(grp_month, model='addition', period=12)
```

This gives me the output:

| Month | Out |
| --- | --- |
| 2018-01-01 | -17707.340278 |
| 2018-02-01 | -49501.548611 |
| 2018-03-01 | -28172.590278 |
| .. | .. |
| .. | .. |
| 2019-12-01 | -13296.173611 |

As you can see in the table, implementing seasonal_decompose() gives me the monthly seasonality. Is there any way I can get the daily data from this?  Or can I convert this into a date wise series?

Edit:
I tried to remove daily seasonality as follows but I'm not really sure if this is the way to go.

```
 period = 365
 season_mean = data.groupby(data.index % period).transform('mean') 
 data -= season_mean
 print(data.head())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to substract these values to a daily DataFrame, you should upsample the DataFrame season_result using pandas.DataFrame.resample this way you will be able to substract the monthly seasonnality from your original one.

Comment: Thanks. I will try using resample from Pandas. Out of curiosity, is there any way I can remove the daily seasonality from a dataframe? So far, I tried doing this: (please see the edits in the question.)